# Show that $z^n+c$ is harmonic, $c\in\mathbb C$.

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I would like to know how to show 
$$f(z) = z^n+c$$
for $c\in \mathbb C$ is harmonic over $D =\{|z|\leq r\}$.

I know that if I express $z = x+iy$, then I can have $f=u+iv$, where $u$ and $v$ will be polynomials. We know polynomials are are analytic over $D$ and hence $f$ is analytic. Since $f$ is analytic, $u$ and $v$ are harmonic.

Is my reasoning correct? Is there a good/faster way to show this rigorously?

Comment: Do you mean harmonic or holomorphic?

Comment: All polynomials in $z$ are holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$ and thus harmonic.

Comment: @ForgotALot Yeah, that's what I'm getting at, I think. This should just be a "well-known" result correct?

Comment: @bartgol I want to show/confirm that $f$ is harmonic.

Comment: Rudin *Real and Complex Analysis* 10.4 (polynomials holomorphic), 11.4 (holomorphic functions harmonic).

Comment: @ForgotALot I am using Gamelin's _Complex Analysis_. I will try to see if I can get Rudin's book. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to change the title a bit. It is not $f$ to be harmonic (in $\mathbb{C}$) but its real and imaginary parts (in $\mathbb{R}^2$)...

Comment: @bartgol Thanks for pointing that out. I might not change it, because I don't want the question to move up the active list. I have a theorem that says "If $f = u+iv$ is analytic, and the functions $u$ and $v$ have continuous second-order partial derivatives, then $u$ and $v$ are harmonic." By your statement, this means $u,v$ are harmonic in $\mathbb R^2$, but what can I say about $f$ (in $\mathbb C$)?

Comment: You already assumed it is analytic. What else can you ask for?

Comment: @bartgol Oh yes! I was careless, haha. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is basically assuming the answer. Your answer amounts to "$f$ is a polynomial, so it is holomorphic, so its components are harmonic". The answer is correct, but it doesn't have any work in.

I would probably feel obliged to prove that $z^n + c$ is holomorphic directly. To do this, note that the sum and product of holomorphic functions is holomorphic, so it suffices to show that $z$ and $c$ are holomorphic functions. $c$ is obviously: it differentiates to $0$. $z$ is obviously: it differentiates to $1$. Tiny amount of work to do there: $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{x+h - x}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} 1 = 1$$

Comment: Yes, this reasoning is much better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It can be proved by the Laplacian in polar coordinates, i.e.
$$
u_{rr}+\frac{u_r}{r}+\frac{u_{\theta\theta}}{r^2}=0\tag1
$$
Since
$$
f(z)=r^ne^{in\theta}+c=r^n\cos{n\theta}+ir^n\sin{n\theta}+c=u+iv
$$
There is
$$
u_{rr}=n(n-1)r^{n-2}\cos{n\theta}
$$
And
$$
\frac{u_{r}}{r}=nr^{n-2}\cos{n\theta}
$$
$$
\frac{u_{\theta\theta}}{r^2}=-n^2r^{n-2}\cos{n\theta}
$$
Hence $u$ satisfies $(1)$ and is harmonic. So is $v$.

Comment: Thank you. I will keep this in mind.